# How to use a variable once, across the equation, in Excel 2007?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

okay, is there a way to declare a variable inside a cell, without calling the cell name 3 times, across the equation(?)?

I came up with this, to calculate the age from a DOB entered using the **=DATE(Y,M,D)** function. Comparing today's date, and using **IF** statements.

In this example, the cell being called is **B5** (containing, DATE(Y,M,D))

```
=YEAR(TODAY())-YEAR(B5)+(IF(MONTH(B5)>MONTH(TODAY()),1,(IF((DAY(B5))<(DAY(TODAY())), 0,1))))-1
```

To make it simpler to give to a co-worker who works in different city, who needs to calculate the age of her clients.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to declare a variable for a cell reference inside a formula. You just have to refer to the cell each time you need to reference its value.

As for simplifying your age calculation formula, you might try the following:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(YEARFRAC(B5,TODAY()),0)
```

Comment: @ThingsOfYourMind I edited my answer to include a formula suggestion as well.